# Слово "скряга"

Tags: этимология

От какого слова образовано слово "скряга"? Мне на ум приходит только "скрежетать"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Словарь Фасмера:
Скряґга, Ближайшая этимология: Наряду со Скрыґга (см.). Из-за расхождений в вокализме трудно объединить эти слова друг с другом. Дальнейшая этимология: Еще не имеет надежной этимологии. Предполагают родство с Крыть (Желтов (ФЗ, 1876, вып. I, стр. 20), Вайан (RЕS 18, 77)). По мнению Соболевского (РФВ 67, 212), связано с Кра, Скра "груда". Младенов (586) сравнивает это слово с болг. диал. Скръґндза "скряга"; Ильинский (РФВ, 78, 200) считает, что это слово восходит к *sker - "резать"; Преобр. (II, 313) предполагает контаминацию Скаґред и Коряґга; Маценауэр (308) -- связь с голл. schrok "обжора" или нем. karg "скупой". Ср. англ. shrink "съеживаться", др.-англ. sсrеnсаn "обманывать, злоупотреблять доверием", д.-в.-н. screnkan (Клюге-ГеЁтце, 542, без русск. слова).

Скрыґга Ближайшая этимология: "скряга". По мнению Вайана (RЕS 18, 77), от Скрыть, Крыть. Ср. Скряґга. (там же)

Answer (score -1):

Слово скряга происходит от британской фамилии (имени, прозвища) Scrooge (Cкрудж) и означает примерно то же, что и у них.